# does kafka support dotnet core?

Tags: apache-kafka, .net-core

I'm trying to make a Kafka producer and consumer, but my project is in dotnet Core 2.0 and it doesn't seem to work well with kafka. This is the proof-of-concept I've tried coming up with. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with the kafka-net nuget package:

using

```
using KafkaNet;
using KafkaNet.Model;
using KafkaNet.Protocol;
```

producer

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string payload = "Welcome to Kafka!";
    string topic = "IDGTestTopic";
    Message msg = new Message(payload);
    Uri uri = new Uri("localhost:9092");
    var options = new KafkaOptions(uri);
    var router = new BrokerRouter(options);
    var client = new Producer(router);
    client.SendMessageAsync(topic, new List<Message> { msg }).Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

consumer

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string topic = "IDGTestTopic";
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9092");
    var options = new KafkaOptions(uri);
    var router = new BrokerRouter(options);
    var consumer = new Consumer(new ConsumerOptions(topic, router));
    foreach (var message in consumer.Consume())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Value));
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I try to run the producer first, I get an error message on the BrokerRouter:

```
$exception  {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: port
at System.Net.IPEndPoint..ctor(IPAddress address, Int32 port)
at KafkaNet.DefaultKafkaConnectionFactory.Resolve(Uri kafkaAddress, IKafkaLog log)
at KafkaNet.Model.KafkaOptions.<get_KafkaServerEndpoints>d__0.MoveNext()
at KafkaNet.BrokerRouter..ctor(KafkaOptions kafkaOptions)
at SampleKafkaProducer.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\v4target\SampleKafka\SampleKafkaProducer\SampleKafkaProducer\Program.cs:line 18}   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

How is a port of 9092 out of range? My Visual Studio projects are running on ports in the 55000's. Multiple sources I've researched use 9092 as a kafka port.

Does anyone understand the error message? Is part of the main problem because I'm using a version of Kafka not compatible with dotnet core?

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace from the exception, that will at least tell you which line of code that caused the exception - that information is priceless.

Comment: Thank you @nos . I've pulled the exact stack trace, but it's leading to the port. The error itself starts at BrokerRouter(), which takes in KafkaOptions, but I can't understand what exactly is the issue here.

Comment: This version of KafkaNet has support for dotnet core https://github.com/snmslavk/kafka-net-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the uri.

> Uri uri = new Uri("localhost:9092");

If you print out the uri.Port, it's -1. Hence the ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Try this instead:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9092");
```

From the [KafkaNet Repository](https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net/blob/c9bbbe61fd519da5a8a7fcb99035bf2cbc5940d3/src/TestHarness/Program.cs#L18). This is how they setup the URI:

```
var options = new KafkaOptions(new Uri("http://CSDKAFKA01:9092"), new Uri("http://CSDKAFKA02:9092"))
{
    Log = new ConsoleLog()
};
```